Clone ntfs partition (with linux) over network
I have two computers running with Linux, they each have a disk attached with a ntfs partion on it (/dev/sda3) -- one contains a Win10 install, the other is empty. What I want to do is to clone the Win10 to the empty partition on the other computer, over the network.
On the client computer, I ran sudo bash -c 'nc 192.168.88.43 22363 | zstd -dvT0 | ntfsclone -r - /dev/sda3' and on the server computer I had sudo ntfsclone -s -o - /dev/sda3 | zstd -16vT0 -o - | nc -l 22363.
Unfortunately, this is not enough. Both are sitting still, with no action happening (I double-checked with btop for network activity).
I get one error message after the start of ntfsclone: error: command cannot be separated from its argument by another command. But ntfsclone proceeds with scanning and finally, Saving NTFS to image .... I assumed that this is more a warning of no relevance.
What is wrong? Do I need to have the nc command on the server run with elevated rights as well?

(1) In what order do you run the commands? It's better to start the listening nc before the connecting nc. (2) Are you sure the firewall on the listening side allows the incoming connection? (3) If you read with ntfsclone -s then the output is not a raw copy, it's a special format specific to the tool; so you need to write it with ntfsclone -r, just dumping the uncompressed stream to /dev/sda3 won't recreate the filesystem. (4) I don't know zstd, looks sane at first glance. // Conclusion: if you manage to connect nc to nc then you should certainly fix (3).

Good advice. I corrected my question with ntfsclone incorporated on the receiving side as well. Unfortunately, no dice; still can't get anything to happen. I need to follow your conclusion and debug the nc - nc connection.

man 8 ntfsclone contains examples and they make me believe your ntfsclone -r - /dev/sda3 has - and /dev/sda3 in the wrong order; and maybe you need --overwrite. Not tested, I just read the manual.

I actually typed this from memory and I had to include --overwrite after the first attempt complained about /dev/sdb3 already existing, you are right. But as you said, it shouldn't be ntfsclone as the culprit. There's something wrong with the nc connection. I'm on it, but it will take some time.

The above could actually be a test question, since it's solvable without knowing too much details about the tools used.
There's a client (the receiver), and a server (the sender). But the client is the one with the 'netcat send' command and the server the one with nc -l, 'netcat listen'. No wonder that this won't work, the parts need to be switched.
With
sender:
sudo ntfsclone -s -o - /dev/sda3 | zstd -16vT0 | nc emk-hc4.lan 22363
and
receiver:
nc -l 22363 | zstd -dvT0 | sudo ntfsclone -O /dev/sda3 -r -
everything works like it should. No warnings or error messages on either sender or receiver.
With a bit of refinement for Gigabit ethernet speed, processor load1 and removing the need for Ctrl-c on the sender side after the process has finished, we arrive at the following
Instructions for cloning a ntfs partition over the network with linux

Start the client/listener first with

nc -l 22363 | zstd -dvT0 | sudo ntfsclone -O /dev/sda3 -r -
(port number after nc -l can be randomly chosen, but needs to be the same on client and server)

After that, start the sender/server with

sudo ntfsclone -s -o - /dev/sda3 | zstd -11vT0 | nc -q 5 192.168.1.12 22363
(replace IP address with the IP/name of your client/receiver and use the same port number as on your client)
The contents of the ntfs partition are then sent over to the receiver, and 5 seconds after the sender runs out of data to send, the connection terminates.
Typical result on a i7-4810MQ 2.80 GHz over Gigabit LAN, partition about 41 GB full (Windows with Office suite):
time sudo ntfsclone -s -o - /dev/sdc3 | zstd -11vT0 | nc -q 5 emk-hc4.lan 22363
*** Zstandard CLI (64-bit) v1.5.6, by Yann Collet ***
Note: 4 physical core(s) detected 
ntfsclone v2022.10.3 (libntfs-3g)
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 156238868480 bytes (156239 MB)
Current device size: 156238872576 bytes (156239 MB)
Scanning volume ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use       : 40609 MB (26,0%)   
Saving NTFS to image ...
100.00 percent completed - Consumed: 37.8 GiB - Compressed: 19.1 GiB => 50.42%  99,99 percent completed
Syncing ...
/*stdin*\            : 50.45%   (  37.8 GiB =>   19.1 GiB, /*stdout*\)         

real    13m26,674s
user    32m51,816s
sys     1m14,848s

It took 47 min 33 s to send 40609 MB over, with the CPU load around 30 - 40% and the network load for the Gigabit connection around 14 - 15 MB/s on average and 30 - 40% during bursts. This seems to be a good spot for both network and CPU. Decoding effort on client side is negligible.

[1] https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2017/03/07/better-compression-with-zstandard/

"No wonder that this won't work" – I do wonder. A TCP connection from nc to nc is bi-directional (e.g. if you type and hit Enter where nc … | … runs then you will see the text printed where … | nc … runs. I piped data to a listening nc and the data went through once another nc connected. The important thing is to start the listener first. If your solution works only after switching the side that listens then probably a firewall, NAT or something similar makes you unable to initiate connections in one direction, while connections in the opposite direction can be initiated.

The first thing I checked after I had time for this was the existence of a firewall. Nope, none whatsoever. Maybe the 'brand' of netcat plays a role. It's netcat-openbsd here on both sides. I know that the connection is bi-di, but maybe the initiation is one-sided?
